# Layering elements in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a website (that I have spent months developing):

```css
body {
  height: 1920px;
}

.h1 {
  position: fixed;
  color: #333;
}

.h2 {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="1">
<h1 class="h1">
Hi
</h1>
</div>

<div class="2">
<h2 class="h2">
Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. Bye. 
</h2>
</div>
```

However, as you can see, the red text is covering the black text and I am not sure why. How would I make it so the red text is below the black text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `z-index:` CSS rule to your `<nav>` element:

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/vbbh6c6x/

```
.nav{
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}
```

This changes the stacking order of elements.

**Ensure the `<nav>` element also has as CSS `position:`**  stated otherwise the `z-index:` rule will have no effect (it doesn't need to be in the same rule declaration, but somewhere in the CSS `.nav` should have an explicit `position:`)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
.nav { z-index:2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be `z-index` ,

Modify your code like this.

```
.nav ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
z-index: 1; /*added for submenu*/
 }
```

Hope this help.!

Answer (score 0):

Add a z-index to your nav class, this will allow the drop down to go over the image slider.

```
.nav {
   background-color: #222;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 99999; /* Add this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Z-index in your CSS will do the trick e.g;

```
.h1 {
  z-index:100
}
```

Most browsers support up to 2147483647 value for z-index.